# Google Now gives absurd times for arriving on time

Tags: google-now

Google Now gives me absurd times in its notifications when it think I should leave the house. Just now, at 9:05 pm, it told me that I have to leave at 6:20 am for an event at 10 pm. 9:20 pm would actually be realistic. What may be causing this?

I have enabled Automatic Date & Time as well as Automatic Time Zone. I'm in Central European Summer Time; the clock works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled *Location Services*? Google Now determines the time you may take to get to your appointments from your **synced calendars** and your **current location**. I am sure you have synced calendars because Google Now reports an appointment. Location Services maybe an issue. If you are using the stock ROM for your device, enable Location Services and sign into *Latitude* to set your current location. Setting your location manually may also solve your problem. If you are on a custom ROM, you can set the device up to use only the *Internal GPS* to report your current location to Google Now. Hope this helps. If you give this a shot, report back with results for others to help you or be helped.

P.S.: [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/10367/17688) may be useful.